# Can I use a different voltage / amp to what the device is rated?

Tags: power-supply

Please bear with me as my knowledge on electrical is very limited.

*Background*

- Question relates to a driving simulator product = Thrustmaster T500
- Product uses a 24v / 6.67a 4 pin power supply (factory supplied)

*Context*

- I intend to purchase one but it does not come with a power supply
- I can source one on Amazon / Ebay but it is extremely expensive ($100AUD)
- The product will be used in Australia.
- There is someone who has used a 19v / 7.1a laptop power supply and simply cut the wires (male from power unit / femal in the base) and connected the positive and negatives back together in order to power the unit.
- They claim everything works, and been using it for over a year with no problems

*Concerns*

- I understand if I do this I will lose any warranty on the base
- Unsure if not using recommended volt/amp is a wise decision
- Asthetically it will look ugly as its hard to hide all the wires
- The only Pro is that the cost will be very minimal, especially if I can find a 2nd hand laptop PSU

*Question*

- Is doing it the "cheap" way possible and logical ?
- What are the implications of using the non recommended volt/amp

BTW - I tried to find an answer to no avail. Thanks heaps for reading up this far and your feedback will be greatly appreciated :)

Kind regards

Gary

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it because you simply don't know what circutry that powers: it could be anything, and the steering wheel looks expensive enough to avoid risking a new unit.

I have this:
https://www.tooq.com/product.php?id=1521

Available for 20 € where I'm based (Madrid):
https://www.pccomponentes.com/tooq-tqlc-100bs01m-cargador-universal-portatiles-100w

It even comes in an aluminium case which is great for heat dissipation. I bought it to power a laptop from a camper van battery, as it does both AC-DC and DC-DC step up and it works really well.

Since it comes from China, maybe in Australia you can find something like that, but good for the 160 W you need.

In fact, I would check the actual consumption of the steering wheel, I wouldn't be surprised if it's well below those 6.7 A. Can you get hold of a lab power supply and a multimeter for this quick check?

Comment: I tried to find those "multi" adapters too ... but nothing comes in the male plug that I am after :(

Unfortunately i cannot test it as I haven't purchased the product yet and don't know anyone who has one. But if your theory is true ... (doesn't use the whole 6.7a) are you inferring that a smaller ampage can be used without issues ?

Comment: Yes... I don't really know why, but I've seen different equipment drawing significantly less than stated. As the DC supply current is simply a maximum rating, it's fine to draw any current that's "<=" that rating... worth checking with an ammeter.